# How to create a schedule in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have to implement a schedule in `Silverlight`.
I've found the needed design [here](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#ScheduleView/FirstLook)

Could somebody tell me how to:

1. Allow mouseMove only for one row (e.g. one day)?
2. Paint mouseMove range?
3. Obtain the selected timeSpan?

Tnx in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You should read the FAQ and know that such broad questions are likely to be closed.   I suggest you start with point 1 and have a go yourself, if you find you are having a problem then open a new question, include some sample code and describe what problem you are having.